# Seeking Advice on Transferring Foreign Exchange Credits and Degree Completion

Tags: undergraduate, degree, student-exchange

I'm facing a bit of a unique situation regarding my academic credits and would appreciate some guidance.

Background:

- I was a foreign exchange student in the US for one semester. Upon returning to Sweden, I was informed that due to differences in grading systems, my US grades would not be graded, just credited as long as I passed the courses. I passed all courses except for one. However, they were all marked as "credited" without specific US grade records.
- Recently, I discovered that the course I failed has been deprecated at my Swedish university.

Current situation:

- The deprecation of this course has created an obstacle in obtaining my degree, as I need to pass it to graduate.
- Unfortunately, my university no longer offers this course.
- At this moment my university has marked the course as "credited" even though I failed.

Possible solutions that I can see:

- Enrolling in a similar course at a different Swedish university, hoping it will be accepted as a substitute by my home university.
- Contacting my university directly to discuss the issue and seek their advice.
- Applying for my degree and seeing if this specific course will be overlooked.

Advice:

- Should I directly approach my university about this issue or first attempt to find a substitute course?

I recognize that this situation is completely my fault. I should've checked the status of this course and prioritized passing it. If anyone has encountered a similar situation or has insights on navigating credit transfers and course deprecations, your input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course you need to talk to your university. I don't understand why you are asking random people on the internet this rather than directly asking the people who make the final decisions. What can we tell you that they cannot?

Comment: @MaartenBuis You are right. I guess someone just had to tell me the obvious. I've been kind of scared about what the university might say, but that's no excuse for not facing reality. I just hope that I will be able to finish my degree one way or another. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only your university can settle this for you, so you need to ask and find a way to live with the consequences. If you talk this over with someone in authority (a department head, dean, ...) they can confirm your situation.

However, since the university no longer offers the course in question, they should also be able to give you an alternative that will bring you back into compliance with the rules. Such accommodations are pretty common. "Sorry, we made a change so you can't graduate" isn't a productive way for a university to behave. They have an incentive to find a way. It might delay you a bit, but open a door, at least. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your perspective. It really helps to hear someone else's take on this, and it has made me feel a bit better about talking to the university. Hopefully, I will be able to graduate later, but I guess I'll find out for sure once I speak with them. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You want to start with some sort of advisory office at your institution, not with the records office: The latter could be sympathetic, but they probably can't help you. They may know who to refer you to, though. Almost every institution has some sort of office for people who need to solve non-standard problems, and that's who you want.

If you can think of an idea of how the problem might be solved (such as taking another course that you suggested), you could bring this up as a possibility, but don't start with that. It would not be crazy to simply ask them to remove the "credit - fail" from a foreign university from your record, particularly if you can give a good reason. They may well not allow that, but will likely still be willing to discuss "how can we solve this problem".

The university absolutely never intended that taking some foreign exchange courses would prevent you from graduating. People often get bad grades in foreign exchange programs, either because of language difficulty or because the assumptions about what background you have going into a course are very different. Is there a specific office that organizes those? They may also have suggestions.